# How to improve the accuracy of the data involved in the calculation?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I want to draw the error of [the two iterative methods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231073/how-can-i-determine-the-convergence-rate-of-recurrence-methods/231079#231079).

```
ListPlot@Block[{$MinPrecision = 50, $MaxPrecision = 50}, 
  Log[Table[
    Abs[Nest[Power[# + 1, (3)^-1] &, 1., i] - 
      Root[#^3 - # - 1 &, 1]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]]]
ListPlot@Block[{$MinPrecision = 50, $MaxPrecision = 50}, 
  Log[Table[
    Abs[Nest[(2 #^3 + 1)/(3 #^2 - 1) &, 1., i] - 
      Root[#^3 - # - 1 &, 1]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]]]
```

However, the accuracy of the second iteration method is not enough to draw the parabola completely.

[image]

What can I do to improve the accuracy of drawing and get the correct scatter plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't start with machine precision.
2. Increase precision.

.

```
ListPlot@Block[{$MinPrecision = 1000, $MaxPrecision = 1000}, 
  Log[Table[
    Abs[Nest[(2 #^3 + 1)/(3 #^2 - 1) &, 1.`1000, i] - 
      Root[#^3 - # - 1 &, 1]], {i, 1, 10, 1}]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.